# Не парсит данные, собирает лишь часть

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping

Надо спарсить названия брендов.
https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/hoodies-2/items.aspx?page=1&view=90&sort=4&q=hoodie
При парсинге собираются данные только для первых 12 позиций, дальше почему то, данные не собирает. Название бренда лежит в теге p, который лежит в теге li. Всего на первой странице 90 позиций, которые надо получить, но почему то достаются данные только для первых двенадцати позиций.В коде сначала нахожу все div, с классом ltr-1bvlx7l e1awqx90, в них через цикл нахожу теги p, с классом e17j0z620 ltr-17q7kb6-Body-BodyBold eq12nrx0. В итоге получаю список с 12-ю элементами, а надо чтобы было 90 элементов. На 12-м элементе код останавливается, ошибок никаких нет, просто не собирает дальше данные.

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/hoodies-2/items.aspx?page=1&view=90&sort=4&q=hoodie"
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = r.text

soup = bs(src, 'lxml') 
items = soup.find_all("div", class_="ltr-1bvlx7l e1awqx90")
spisok = []
for item in items:
    all_products_hrefs = item.find("p", class_="e17j0z620 ltr-17q7kb6-Body-BodyBold eq12nrx0").get_text()
    spisok.append(all_products_hrefs)
    time.sleep(1)

print(spisok)
```

это результат который получаю

```
['Alpha Industries', 'Alpha Industries', 'adidas', 'PRÉVU', 'adidas', 'FIVE CM', 'FIVE CM', 'Fila', 'Reigning Champ', 'Ecoalf', 'FIVE CM', 'Dickies Construct']


  [Скриншот страницы с исходным кодом]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXxCG.jpg
```

Comment: Может быть такое, что на страницу сначала загружается именно 12 позиций товара, а остальные подгружаются динамически?

Comment: нет, тоже думал что динамическая страница, но данные грузятся сразу

Comment: А сайт то динамический, на пераой странице уже есть 12 позиций товара, а остальные подгружаются динамически.  Проверяйте информацию, а не гадайте по кофейной гуще.

Comment: Никто не гадает, сказал как есть, опыта не много в парсинге. Поэтому и задал вопрос чтобы решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт динамический. Отлавливайте запросы или используйте селенимум

```
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0',
}
page = 1
params = {
    'page': page,
    'view': '90',
    'sort': '4',
    'q': 'hoodie',
    'pagetype': 'Shopping',
    'rootCategory': 'Men',
    'pricetype': 'FullPrice',
    'c-category': '136398',
}
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.farfetch.com/uk/plpslice/listing-api/products-facets',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
)
items = response.json()['listingItems']['items']
for i, x in enumerate(items, 1):
    print(f'-- {i} --')
    print(f"{x['shortDescription']} ({x['brand']['name']})")
    print(x['priceInfo']['formattedFinalPrice'])
    print('https://www.farfetch.com' + x['url'])

-- 1 --
logo drawstring hoodie (Alpha Industries)
£29
https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/alpha-industries-logo-drawstring-hoodie-item-17965530.aspx?storeid=11155
-- 2 --
logo-print drawstring hoodie (Alpha Industries)
£31
https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/alpha-industries-logo-print-drawstring-hoodie-item-17964433.aspx?storeid=11155

...

-- 89 --
logo-patch long-sleeve hoodie  (FIVE CM)
£70
https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/five-cm-logo-patch-long-sleeve-hoodie-item-19287933.aspx?storeid=12667
-- 90 --
logo-embroidered drawstring hoodie (Sun 68)
£70
https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/sun-68-logo-embroidered-drawstring-hoodie-item-19153139.aspx?storeid=12045
```

Comment: А где нашли  эту ссылку на json, 'https://www.farfetch.com/uk/plpslice/listing-api/products-facets'. С динамикой разобрался, действительно, когда пролистываешь страницу в тегах li наполняются дивы информацией. Теперь подвис на том, откуда достать эту ссылку на json. Пробовал скролить страницу и искать в Fetch/XHR но там не могу найти этот JSON? Извиняюсь заранее за глупый вопрос

Comment: перейдите на следующую страницу,  Смотрим запросы в инструментах веб-разработчика, акладка 'сеть', фильтр XHR

Comment: Благодарю, нашел

Comment: Selenium использовать довольно вредный совет. Для динамики есть библиотека requests_html.